# Add headers in response in user plugin

Tags: plugins, repository, artifactory

When retrieving a file from Artifactory, I would like to return its properties as HTTP headers.

Attempting to add headers to the response of a file download in the **altResponse** code block of the **download** plugin does not appear to work as I thought it would.

With the following user plugin loaded, I can see the code being executed from the logs, however, the header is not included in the response (using `curl` to download the file)

```
import org.artifactory.repo.RepoPath
import org.artifactory.request.Request

download {
    altResponse { Request request, RepoPath responseRepoPath ->
        headers = ["ExtraHeader":"SpecialHeader"]
        log.warn "adding header: $headers"
    }
}
```

logs:

```
2018-05-07 17:28:04,969 [http-nio-8088-exec-4] [WARN ] (properties          :7) - adding header: [ExtraHeader:SpecialHeader]
```

documentation:

- https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins#UserPlugins-Download

Running artifactory plugin development locally (currently loads version 5.11.0)

- https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins-devenv

Am I misunderstanding how `headers` is supposed to be used?

Comment: Did you solve this already?
I would try `altAllResponses` instead of `altResponse` because you really want to _(3) Setting response headers_.
I believe that the documentation is wrong for the `altResponse`